# Laravel returns error 500 after uploading to web host via FTP

Tags: laravel

I am trying to access my API and I get error 500 after uploading it to my FTP.
Laravel located at: `MYDOMAIN.COM/v2/api`

no error logs are generated.

My public `index.php` is the default one. Tried to play with it, but the paths seem fine.

What could have gone wrong?

For the reminder, it is a different domain. I do edit the config/app.php

Comment: Is the vendor folder uploaded?

Comment: did you set permissions that are needed as per the install docs, if they are needed on this server?

Comment: @Marwelln Yes it is.

Comment: @lagbox All I know is permission for the storage folder, and I gave it 777

Comment: Is .env file uploaded?

Comment: @huuuk yes, everything uploaded

Comment: It seems that something wrong with storage logs folder permissions  , if no logs were generated

Comment: Have you got both bootstrap/cache and storage/ correct rights ? Have you got access to your webserver logs (Apache or Nginx or whatever) ?

Comment: recursive permissions for storage and bootstrap/cache ?

Answer (score 1):

Some things i experienced:

1. Run a composer install in case you moved your project. (I did this sometimes and skipped the vendor folder)
2. Just give your storage folder the right permissions:
   `chown -R www-data.www-data /var/www/laravel
   $ chmod -R 755 /var/www/laravel
   $ chmod -R 777 /var/www/laravel/app/storage`
   assad
3. Finally check your server settings. If your virtualhost has a wrong directory path the things above doesn't matter.

```
    ServerName laravel.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/laravel/public

    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/laravel>
            AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Credit: http://tecadmin.net/install-laravel-framework-on-ubuntu/#